When using react three csg and fiber with subtractions applied to uploaded stl files, exported stl file does not include subtraction
I'm using react three csg with fiber, and uploading stl files on to the scene.   I then apply a subtraction on the uploaded files, which works, but when I export the geometries to an stl file, the generated stl has multiple issues:

The scale is about 5% of what it should be
The object is upside down
The two objects that should be subtracting are combined
The axis objects appear

Screenshots here:
(first is my react app, second is the exported stl from three being loaded into tinkercad )
my react app
resulting exported stl
Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/practical-taussig-qwklgc?workspaceId=153aa09e-cc76-4115-ad44-a74d90d761fa
Here is my code:


import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Geometry, Base, Subtraction, Addition } from '@react-three/csg'
import { STLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader'
import { Environment } from './Environment'
import { OrbitControls, PivotControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import { BufferAttribute } from 'three'
import { STLExporter } from 'three/examples/jsm/exporters/STLExporter.js'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber'

function App() {
  const [stlModel, setStlModel] = useState(null)
  const [stlModelB, setStlModelB] = useState(null)
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1)
  const csgA = useRef()
  const csgRef = useRef()
  const csgRefB = useRef()

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const reader = new FileReader(file)

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const loader = new STLLoader()
      const geometry = loader.parse(e.target.result)
      setStlModel(geometry)
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  }

  const handleFileBChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const reader = new FileReader(file)

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const loader = new STLLoader()
      const geometry = loader.parse(e.target.result)
      setStlModelB(geometry)
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  }

  function traverseChildren(children) {
    console.log(' THE CHILDSS ', children)
    for (const child of children) {
      console.log(' CHILD ', child)
      console.log(child.isMesh)
      console.log(child.children)
      if (child.isMesh) {
        // Do something with the mesh
      }
      if (child.children) {
        traverseChildren(child.children)
      }
    }
  }

  const handleExport = () => {
    const csg = csgRef.current

    if (csg) {
      traverseChildren(csg.children)
    }
    if (csg) {
      const exporter = new STLExporter()
      const stlData = exporter.parse(csg)
      const blob = new Blob([stlData], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.download = 'myModel.stl'
      link.click()
    }
  }

  const handleReset = () => {
    setStlModel(null)
    setStlModelB(null)
  }

  const ready = stlModel && stlModelB

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100vw', height: '90vh' }}>
      {!ready && (
        <div>
          <div>Upload two stl files below. The second will be subtracted from the first</div>
          <br />
          <input type="file" accept=".stl" onChange={handleFileChange} />
          <input type="file" onChange={handleFileBChange} />
        </div>
      )}
      {ready && (
        <Canvas shadows camera={{ position: [-15, 10, 15], fov: 55 }} ref={csgRefB}>
          {stlModel && (
            <>
              <color attach="background" args={['skyblue']} />
              <ModelRender scale={scale} geom={stlModel} csgA={csgA} geomB={stlModelB} csgRef={csgRef} />
              <Environment />
              <OrbitControls makeDefault />
            </>
          )}
        </Canvas>
      )}
      {ready && (
        <div>
          <span>CHANGE SCALE OF FIRST STL OBJ</span>
          <input type="range" min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value={scale} onChange={(e) => setScale(parseFloat(e.target.value))} />
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={() => handleExport()}>export and download stl</button>
          <>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</>
          <button onClick={() => handleReset()}>reset app</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

function ModelRender({ scale, geom, geomB, csgA, csgRef }) {
  geom.setAttribute(`uv`, new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([]), 1))
  return (
    <mesh ref={csgRef} receiveShadow castShadow rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0, -3, 0]} scale={[0.02, 0.02, 0.02]}>
      <Geometry useGroups ref={csgA}>
        <Base scale={scale} geometry={geom}>
          <meshPhysicalMaterial color={`green`} />
        </Base>
        <PivotControls activeAxes={[true, true, true]} rotation={[0, Math.PI, 0]} scale={100} anchor={[0.4, 0, 0]} onDrag={() => csgA.current.update()}>
          <Window geom={geomB} />
        </PivotControls>
      </Geometry>
    </mesh>
  )
}

function Window({ geom }) {
  geom.setAttribute(`uv`, new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([]), 1))
  return (
    // <Geometry>
    //   <mesh geometry={geom} />
    // </Geometry>
    <Subtraction geometry={geom}>
      <meshPhysicalMaterial color={`red`} />
    </Subtraction>
  )
}

export default App
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




If possible, please share a minimal reproducible example. Don't use external links.
